# userData for an iOS UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using Core Data to manage Thing(s) and then UITableViewController/UITableViewCell to present a list of Things.  However, a Thing object has more data than just what I display in the text property of the UITableViewCell, and when I segue from the UITableViewController to a more detailed view controller of Thing, what I really want is a pointer to the Thing object so I can pass it on to the next view controller.

For example:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITAbleView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
ENTRY_LOG;
// Ask the NSFetchedResultsController for the NSManagedUserObject at the row in question
Thing* thing = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// For brevity skip dequeueReusable...

 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 cell.textLabel.text = thing.name;

 EXIT_LOG;
 return cell;
```

Now, assume I assume the segue connected appropriately:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender {
  ENTRY_LOG;

  UITableViewCell* cellSender = (UITableViewCell*)sender;

  // I want to do this:
  Thing* thingHandle = [cellSender someMessageToGetThingReference];
  [segue.destinationViewController setThing:thing];

  // and I don't want to do this
  // setup NSFetchRequest and predicate to get thing where 'name = cellSender.text'
  [segue.destinationViewController setThing:thing];      

  EXIT_LOG;
}
```

If I could get the indexPath that the cell is at I could then use my NSFetchResultsController to at least get the objectAtIndexPath again, perhaps call - (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow in the prepareForSegue against the UITableView and proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am missing something obvious, but to get the cell's index path, assuming you are segueing from a UITableViewController, can't you use:

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForCell:cellSender];

Comment: Thanks you! Your solution solve all my problems with UITableViewCell!